# What is the Scaling factor S?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

The question is as follows :
A laser beam is Rayleigh distributed. If the measured current is below 5 mA, very high gain is needed for proper detection; and if the measured current is above 20 mA, the device is likely to be damaged. Assume that the average power is equivalent to 200 ${mA}^2$ . It is decided to put threshold devices immediately following detection. That is the system only responds when the current is between 5 and 20 mA.

I was trying to solve a Rayleigh's probability density function and find the mean of it. It is given that :

E{x^2} = 200

f(x) = (x/100)e^(-x^2/200)

```
f(x)= { 0 for x<5
        S*(x/100)e^(-x^2/200) for 5<x<20
        0 for x>20 }
```

It was stated that integral f(x) should equal 1 which is why a scaling factor S is added. I have never seen a scaling factor added before. Could anyone explain why this is needed? Or provide any articles to read more about this

Below is an image of the article I found

[image: Partial solution]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of distribution is a truncated distribution. One property of a distribution density function $f(x)$ is that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx=1$.

If the distribution is trancated and no scaling factor is involved the integral is not equal to $1$. Let´s say you have

$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx=c$, with $a,b>0$ and $a<b$

$c$ is not equal to $1$. To ensure that $c=1$ we have to divide the the LHS by $F(b)-F(a)$.

$\frac{1}{F(b)-F(a)}\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx=1 \quad (*)$

Therefore $S=\frac{1}{F(b)-F(a)}$

If you multiply the equation (*) by $F(b)-F(a)$ it becomes obvious that this equation must be true.

$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx=F(b)-F(a)$